# How to use images in the array in the react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, react-props

I am creating a website. I am a beginner. **I have an issue.  I have an array of react components. I don’t know can I use React components as the array elements. They are images, imported from the folder of my project.** Also, I have an array of names of news companies. **The idea is to create blocks with the name and image above. I want to create blocks according to the my images array length. So if the length of this array is 4, the cards I have 4. The issue is I can't display images, I imported them to my project.** Main code is in the main page component. Also, I have a component called Author Card. In it, I have a React component, that receives name and image as the props and put them in the card Html block.

Here is my main page component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import AuthorCard from "./MainPageComponents/AuthorCard";
import BBC_Logo from '../assets/images/BBC_Logo.png';
import FOX_Logo from '../assets/images/FOX_Logo.png';
import CNN_Logo from '../assets/images/CNN_logo.png';
import ForbesLogo from '../assets/images/forbes-logo.png';

function MainPage(props) {

    const channels = [
        {
            name: 'BBC',
            index: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'FOX',
            index: 2
        },
        {
            name: 'CNN',
            index: 3
        },
        {
            name: 'FORBES',
            index: 4
        },
    ];

    const logos = [
        <BBC_Logo key={1} />,
        <FOX_Logo key={2}/>,
        <CNN_Logo key={3}/>,
        <ForbesLogo key={4}/>
    ];

    return (
        <div className="main-page">
           <div className="main-page_container">
               <section className="main-page_channels">
                   {channels.map( (channel) => {
                       logos.map( (logo) => {
                           return <AuthorCard name={channel.name} img={logo} />
                       })
                   })}
               </section>
           </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default MainPage;
```

Here is my Author Card component code:

```
import React from 'react';

function AuthorCard(props) {
    return (
        <div className="author-card">
            <div className="author-img">
                {props.img}
            </div>
            <div className="author-name">
                {props.name}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default AuthorCard;
```

**Please, help!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would handle this a bit differently. First thing the way you import your logos is not imported as a component. Rather you get the path/src of the image which you can then use in a  component. Read more about that here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

So the way I would do this is to put the logo img src into your channels array and then pass that img src to the AuthorCard component. Then in the AuthorCard component your use a  component to render the image. Like this:

```
import React from "react";
import BBC_Logo from "../assets/images/BBC_Logo.png";
import FOX_Logo from "../assets/images/FOX_Logo.png";
import CNN_Logo from "../assets/images/CNN_logo.png";
import ForbesLogo from "../assets/images/forbes-logo.png";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MainPage />
    </div>
  );
}

const channels = [
  {
    name: "BBC",
    index: 1,
    img: BBC_Logo
  },
  {
    name: "FOX",
    index: 2,
    img: FOX_Logo
  },
  {
    name: "CNN",
    index: 3,
    img: CNN_Logo
  },
  {
    name: "FORBES",
    index: 4,
    img: ForbesLogo
  }
];

function MainPage(props) {
  return (
    <div className="main-page">
      <div className="main-page_container">
        <section className="main-page_channels">
          {channels.map((channel) => {
            return <AuthorCard name={channel.name} img={channel.img} />;
          })}
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function AuthorCard(props) {
  return (
    <div className="author-card">
      <div className="author-img">
        <img src={props.img} alt="author card" />
      </div>
      <div className="author-name">{props.name}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```